# How to prove that CNOT and Rz gates are permutable?

Tags: quantum-gate, mathematics

How to prove that CNOT and Rz gates are permutable?

I tried to equate their switch to zero and calculate it, but for this you need to multiply the matrices. But the 4x4 and 2x2 matrices cannot be multiplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth thinking about $R_Z$ as being a linear combination of both $I$ and $Z$. So, if (cNOT and I) and (cNOT and Z) are both permutable, then so is cNOT and $R_Z$. Trivially, cNOT and I commute, so the first condition is true. So, we just need to know about how cNOT and Z interact. There are two circuit identities that are worth knowing, depending on whether the Z is on the control or target qubit:
[image]

From this, we see that Z applied to the control permutes with the cNOT. But Z applied to the target does not.

In order to verify the maths, the calculation you need to perform is
$$
(Z\otimes I)\cdot cNOT-cNOT\cdot(Z\otimes I)=0
$$
(remember that there is a second qubit present, so when it does nothing, that is equivalent to applying the identity matrix to it. This is how the $2\times 2$ matrix Z becomes a $4\times 4$ matrix $Z\otimes I$.)

Answer (score 1):

You can represent the effect of a single-qubit gate $Rz$ on a two-qubit system by constructing a 4x4 matrix $Rz \otimes I$ or $I \otimes Rz$, depending on whether you want to apply the gate to the first qubit or the second one. After that, you can do the check the usual way you'd do it for matrices of the same size.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first look at the [controlled Z gate](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.CZGate.html). Almost by definition, it can be written as $CZ=|0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes I+|1\rangle\langle1|\otimes Z$ where the first qubit is the control and the second in the target. From this it is clear that $CZ$ commutes with both $I\otimes R_Z$ and $R_Z\otimes I$.

Now, $CNOT=(I\otimes H) CZ (I\otimes H)$. Since the Hadamard gate $H$ interchanges $R_Z$ and $R_X$, it follows that $CNOT$ commutes with $R_Z\otimes I$ and $I\otimes R_X$.